# How to convert a json response from volley that is too big to be done in the UI thread?

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, android-volley

I have been looking into volley and basically all the example are similar to the following [from the official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html):

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

So my understanding is that we do a request in a background thread and Volley takes care of these details and we get the response in the UI thread when the `onResponse` method is called i.e.

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
```

My question is what happens if the JSONObject response from the server is non-trivial, actually quite big and to update the UI we need to map to a e.g. GSON class to get the fields we need?
I assume doing the conversion inside the `onResponse` is the wrong thing since the conversion could be time consuming and we will be doing that in the UI thread.
I guess I could fire an new thread at that point but getting the results from that new thread to update the UI in the UI thread can get messy.
I believe this should be a standard problem so there must be a standard clean solution/approach.
What is the clean/standard approach for this conversion?

Comment: You can use an AsyncTask for that. It provides you call backs for the UI updation.

Comment: you really should be doing any network calls on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have an `AsyncTack` that parses `JSON` asynchronously, and have it accept a custom `Interface` that the caller implements as a parameter, having a method like:

```
void onResult(Object dataReturned);
```

After `dataReturned` object is created asynchronously in the AsyncTask, I just use that parameter of the `AsyncFunction` as a callback to the original caller.

```
mCaller.onResult(data);
```

I do not know of any standard or predefined way to do this.

Comment: So it is something separate from Volley flow? Would it be possible to add a small sample in your answer?